# PHP Generate Array from Function Arguments

Tags: php, arrays

I have a function that I want to generate an array with. The format of the array is specific and only values need to be changed based on the arguments of my function. Here's the function:

```
 function generatearray($name1, $field1, $name2, $field2) {
  $language = ($user->language) ? $user->language : 'und';
   $edit = array(
    $name1 => array(
     $language => array(
      0 => array(
       'value' => $field1,
     ),
    ),
   ), // ..... other elements $name2
  );
  return $edit;
}
```

$name2 and $field2 are optional arguments.

Comment: It may not answer your question, but you're not defining `$user` anywhere - you need to either pass it in as a parameter, or declare it as a global.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I ended up defining $user as a 5th argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what the question is...but this code will do exactly what you're wanting to know about...a way to build an array based on up to 2 name/value pairs provided to a function.

```
printarray(generatearray('name_one','field_one','name_two','field_two'));

function generatearray($name1, $field1, $name2 = null, $field2 = null) {
$new_array = array();
$language = isset($user->language) ? $user->language : 'und';
$new_array[$name1][$language] = $field1;
if (!is_null($name2) && !is_null($field2)) {
    $new_array[$name2][$language] = $field2;
}
return $new_array;
}

function printarray($arr) {
foreach ($arr as $user_key => $user_value) {
    echo "User: ".$user_key."<br />";
    foreach ($user_value as $language_key=>$language_value) {
        echo "Language: ".$language_value."<br />";
    }
}
}
```